# Is it possible to blacklist certain routes of Microsoft Graph API from a customer Azure Portal?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Some of the scopes for resources in the Microsoft Graph API are too sensitive like Mail.Send to be granted as an application permission through an entire company.

- Send Mail : `POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail` allows you to impersonate someone to send an email (very sensitive)
- Send Message : `POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/send` allows you to send the order to send an email, without having the right to modify it (less sensitive)

Is there a way through **policies** in the Enterprise Application in Azure Portal to force some of the request made to the Microsoft Graph API to send a 403 (or anything else), ensuring sensitive routes cannot be used by an external service ? Or a kind of Microsoft Graph API **proxy** that could be installed simply within the customer's Azure ? Or a simple **App Service** in Azure that could handle simply retrieves token and use it on the Microsoft Graph API ?

Answer (score 0):

See [Scoping application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access?view=graph-rest-1.0) from the Graph Documentation:

> Some apps call Microsoft Graph using their own identity and not on behalf of a user. These are usually background services or daemon apps that run on a server without the presence of a signed-in user. These apps make use of OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow to authenticate and are configured with application permissions, which enable such apps to access all mailboxes in a organization on Exchange Online. For example, the `Mail.Read` application permission allows apps to read mail in all mailboxes without a signed-in user.
>
> Administrators who want to limit the app access to a specific set of mailboxes can use the `New-ApplicationAccessPolicy` PowerShell cmdlet to configure access control. This article covers the basic steps to configure an application access policy.

For example:

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy 
  -AppId e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b 
  -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@contoso.com 
  -AccessRight RestrictAccess 
  -Description "Restrict this app to members of distribution group EvenUsers."
```

Comment: Thanks @marc for sharing. This works to restrict perimeters in terms of user mailboxes. In my case, on top of that, i need to to block a specific action made through a specific route through the graph API, because the Mail.Send scope is too "large". More an action blacklisting, which could, in the same way Application Access Policy does, send a 403 when trying to make the associated send mail action with a body.